# .htaccess rewrite rules not working

Tags: htaccess, redirects, subdomain, no-www, multi-subdomains

I need to redirect multiple subdomains to a single subdomain (www) and have found what seems to be a really good guide exactly on point: http://moz.com/learn/seo/redirection

This is the rule Moz is recommending:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} *!^www*.seomoz\.org [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.seomoz.org/$1 [L,R=301]
```

So I used the rule with my own domain as follows:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} *!^www*.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

... which results in the following error:

```
example.com

HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Date: Mon, 27 Apr 2015 23:10:41 GMT
Server: Apache
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Length: 674
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
```

What could be wrong?

Comment: FWIW the asterisk prefix on the `*!^www*.example\.com` _CondPattern_ is likely to be causing your 500 error. The second asterisk in that pattern is also an obvious error. (TBH that almost looks like some MarkDown/formatting gone wrong?!) Unfortunately there seems to be a few mistakes and misinformation in that linked article.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

This should work.

Here is mine:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Hi closetnoc.  Do you know why Moz wrote their rule the way they did?  They are a reputable resource for webmasters, and the page itself is quoted a lot elsewhere, so I'm wondering why their syntax is working for others and not for me.  P.S. Your edited version didn't work either.

Comment: @KnocksX Not sure why. Sites like MOZ get quoted a lot even when they are completely wrong. I like MOZ, but quibble with some of what they are putting out. Still, I use that site a lot for information, but take it with salt. The syntax in the regex (regular expression) was just plain wrong. For example, they were using a wildcard (*) incorrectly just before the not (!) which should be the first character. As well, they did not escape (\) the first (.) in the domain name just after the www. I suspect they were trying to be more generic with the www assuming room for www1 etc.

Comment: I am trying your edited version, and it's not working.

Comment: @KnocksX I adjusted the first example. I also added an example from my own .htaccess. I do it a bit differently, but it redirects non-www to www just fine.

Comment: That still doesn't work.  Note that I need to refer multiple subdomains (e.g forum.example.com, archive.example.com) to www.example.com.

Comment: Do you have forum.example.com and archive.example.com set-up on your web server? You will need to and then create an .htaccess for each site to do a blanket redirect. The code examples are for redirecting non-www to www. It assumes that one site is set-up as example.com with an alias of www.example.com. I would have to check how this is done in the Apache config files.

Comment: Those subdomains don't exist, but they existed under the previous owner of the domain.   That's the reason I need a rule that will redirect all possible subdomains (I don't know how many and which ones existed before) as a "catch-all."  I know this is possible, because domain parking companies do it all the time in order not to lose even a single visitor.  You can just type gibberish.example.com, and the visitor will be taken to the index.

Comment: You won't be able to without the web server knowing where to place the request. You can simply add a *ServerAlias archive.example.com* (for example) in your Apache configuration file. It will require a restart. As well, you will need to create a CNAME for each sub-domain pointing to example.com. Your example gibberish.example.com is likely using a catch-all site which has to be the first site created on a server. It may be possible to create one after the fact, but I would opt for the method above rather than trying the latter. It is just simpler.

Comment: The issue is that I don't know which subdomains existed for which domains before.  Some of them are not indexed or published.  Lots of domains used to use m.example.com for mobile versions and you're not only losing link juice from those links but simply losing visitors that come via referral links and see a server error.  I need a catch-all solution for my entire portfolio.  I used parking companies as an example because they have this solution in place.  Check out http://sdfasdfjlasd.printers.com/ and substitute any other gibberish for the subdomain.  It resolves instantly.

Comment: Except that a catch-all will not work without having a sub-domain defined in the DNS. You can use a wildcard sub-domain in the DNS. Creating a catch-all site is not easy. By default, the first site created could be used for a catch-all. I will look into this and see what I can figure out. It has been a number of years since I fiddled specifically with a catch-all short of using my first site created 8 years ago.

Comment: On the server, see if you can find in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf. If there is no sites-enabled directory then there should be a /etc/apache2/httpd.conf file. It first is preferred. That could possibly be a catch-all. If the file exists, then make sure it is not used for any other site. If you see *DocumentRoot /var/www/html* you're in luck!!

Comment: Not sure if I'm following.  This server is used by lots of sites, and this trick needs to be enabled for all of them.

Comment: Is this a server that the company owns?? Or are you using a hosting company?

Comment: I rent a dedicated server from a hosting company

Comment: Okay. That is good. If you can SSH (shell) in, assuming linux, you should be able to *cd /etc/apache2/*. Do an *ls*. If you see *site-available*, you are half way there. Cd into site-available then do an ls. If you see *000-default.conf*. You are in good shape. You can edit the file and see how the *DocumentRoot* directive is defined. I use *pico* to edit the file, but it is not always installed. If not, then you can use *vi* (if I remember it right).

Comment: I do understand how to locate that file, but if I'm interpreting your suggestion correctly, changing this file will monopolize its functions for just one site on the server.  I need a universal solution that will catch traffic from ALL wildcard subdomains from ALL sites on this server.  Thank you for all your help, but I should probably retire this issue for now, because we are getting deep in the comments, which I believe is against the etiquette at StackExchange.  I have created individual subdomains for the site in question and am redirecting each one separately, for now.  Thanks again.

Comment: The 000-default.conf is often a catch-all site by default. It will satisfy any request that does not match any specifically defined site- hence any sub-domain request your server gets that is not set-up. If you then create a wildcard sub-domain, that should send all non-defined sub-domain requests to the catch-all site where you can then create an .htaccess file to redirect to where-ever you want. That was what I was trying to get to. Sorry if I got confusing. I was driving at a solution.

Comment: I do appreciate all your help :)

Answer (score 0):

The best way to go is to create an .htaccess file with the following contents:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Then copy that file to the document root of each domain. Normally a document root is right in the public_html if your web server is setup like most.

Then use redbot.org and test everything by plugging in each domain.

You should then see at least the following lines for the headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Location: http://www.example.com/
```

If you want another way to do redirects, then don't use .htaccess and don't deal with rewrite rules. Instead, create a script that does redirects. A modern way to do it in PHP is to use the following script.

```
<?php
header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently",true);
header("Location: http://www.example.com/",true);
?>
<html>
<head>
<title>Moved</title>
</head>
<body>
<a href="http://www.example.com">click here to continue.</a>
</body>
</html>
```

If you decide to take on the PHP route, then you need to save the above as the default PHP filename configured for your server which would normally be index.php, and you will have to place that file in every single folder of the subdomain thats meant to be redirected.

Comment: There is more to this question that is not within the question. The OP was trying to apply some of what I offered to sub-domains that do not exist anymore. Waiting to hear from the OP. (see comments) It sounds like they need a wild-card sub-domain in the DNS and a catch-all site (which may already exist). If you want to address this, that would be GREAT!! The OP is not as tech-savvy as you and I, though absolutely fantastic! Any answer that covers this *new* topic should be somewhat detailed.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a silly suggestion, but are you sure the site you are using is linux and uses a htaccess files?

I recently inherited some web properties, only to realise that despite having a htaccess file, changes I was making weren't being applied as the server was Windows, and not linux.

Comment: The .htaccess file wouldn't have triggered a 500 error unless the .htaccess file was being read. However, if you read the comments on closetnoc's answer you will realise there is more to this problem than stated in the question... it seems the server is not actually set up to receive requests to these subdomains!